# Is there a selector (or any way around) for "Adjacent Until..." in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a html layout that will be based of many adjacent sections. I want to have, somewhere between them, some `divs` that would control their appearance.

My html would be something like this:

```
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<div class="color-scheme--violet-red"></div>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<div class="color-scheme--clear"></div>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<div class="color-scheme--violet-red"></div>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
```

And I would want that every `section` that came AFTER a `color-scheme` `div` had a background defined by it, as I was trying with this scss:

```
$white: #fefefe;
$red: #c54839;
$violet: #6c195e;

.section {
    height: 15em;
    background: $white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: $red;
}


.color-scheme--violet-red ~ .section {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, darken($violet, 10%) 0%, darken($red, 10%) 100%);
    color: $white;
}

.color-scheme--clear ~ .section {
    background: $white;
    color: $red;
}
```

Here's a Fiddle with an working example: https://jsfiddle.net/raphaelaleixo/4featqrg/
(The last two sections are white, but they should be colored)

The thing is, as the last sections are both adjacent to the `color-scheme--clear` `div` AND to the `color-scheme--violet-red`, the one that is below in the css file gains priority, and overwrite the other.

My question is: *Is there anyway to - using only html/css - to select every element that is the CLOSEST adjacent to another?*

For this html, I can't nest this sections inside the "color controller" divs, neither I will be sure of how many divs will be until the next "controller" div (If this was know, I could nest multiple "next siblings" selectors and call it a day).

I am *very* opened to any css hacks that could achieve this layout :-)

Thanks!

Comment: the structure will always be the same? You will always have 2 clear and 2 colored section?

Comment: No, that was only an example. I said that I wouldn't know how many ajacent divs will be until the next "color-controller" section. It could be 3 colored + 2 clear + 4 colored, as an example.

Comment: no, I am not talking about the number of sections and adjacent sibling but about the *control color*, they are also random? or you know how many there will be?

Comment: I am trying to create a layout system, so I would let the marketing team create them as they will. The only rule is that is going to need a `color-scheme--clear` between two `color-scheme--[any-color]` (there will be multiple gradient choices).

Comment: is there a maximum of adjacent divs until the next color-controller section? i.e. max of 6 white or 6 colored in a sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One hacky idea is to increase the specifity of each selector consider the previous `color-sheme` before it. So the more `color-sheme` we have before the more the selector will be specific thus it will win the one before it.

Of course, you will need to write many CSS rules depending on how many section you will have. You can consider SASS/LESS to easily generate the code:

```css
.section {
    height: 15em;
    background: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: red;
}


.color-scheme--violet-red ~ .section,
[class*="color-scheme" ] ~ .color-scheme--violet-red ~ .section,
[class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ]  ~ .color-scheme--violet-red ~ .section,
[class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ]  ~ .color-scheme--violet-red ~ .section,
[class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ]  ~ .color-scheme--violet-red ~ .section{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, purple 0%, red 100%);
    color: white;
}

.color-scheme--clear ~ .section,
[class*="color-scheme" ] ~ .color-scheme--clear ~ .section,
[class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ] ~.color-scheme--clear ~ .section,
[class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ] ~.color-scheme--clear ~ .section,
[class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ] ~ [class*="color-scheme" ] ~.color-scheme--clear ~ .section{
    background: white;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<div class="color-scheme--violet-red"></div>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<div class="color-scheme--clear"></div>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<div class="color-scheme--violet-red"></div>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<div class="color-scheme--clear"></div>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<div class="color-scheme--violet-red"></div>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
```

Comment: This is actually nice. Although it don't solve the problem of possible under/over guessing, I think I can set a maximum of _color-schemes_ in the same page much more easier than it would be to set a maximum number of _sections_ 

if you don't mind, I will let this answer opened for a little longer to see if any more creative ideas shows up. If there isn't any, I'll accept yours as an answer, is that ok? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RaphaelAleixo Yes of course, I am against fast accepting especially when it comes to approximate thing, more hack will come for sure ;) I will probably edit with another one too

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a better pure css solution. The idea of a contiguous sibling selector is certainly not new but there still isn't a clean way to do it: https://www.sitepoint.com/contiguous-sibling-selector/

Comment: @cjc yeah, that's exactly the selector I wish that existed. I am still trying to figure out a way using some combination of :not() and something like that, but I am not feeling much hopeful. Thanks a lot for the link.

Answer (score 0):

This would be another hacky solution.  Adding a `+` selector for each `.section`.

Assuming there is a max number of `.sections` in each 'colour' - you could do something like below (see demo)

The difficulty is (obviously) that you would need to write as many `+ .section` as there are possible siblings of the same colour in a given section

Of course, you could use SASS/LESS to generate the code for you but you still would need to find out how many to generate.

```css
.section {
    height: 5em;
    background: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: red;
}

/* up to 4 coloured sections  */
.color-scheme--violet-red + .section,
.color-scheme--violet-red + .section + .section,
.color-scheme--violet-red + .section + .section + .section,
.color-scheme--violet-red + .section + .section + .section + .section
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, purple 0%, red 100%);
    color: white;
}

.color-scheme--clear + .section
{
    background: white;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<div class="color-scheme--violet-red"></div>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<div class="color-scheme--clear"></div>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<div class="color-scheme--violet-red"></div>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<div class="color-scheme--clear"></div>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<div class="color-scheme--violet-red"></div>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<div class="color-scheme--clear"></div>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<section class="section">White</section>
<div class="color-scheme--violet-red"></div>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
<section class="section">Colored</section>
```

Comment: Hi, @Ochi. This is the "nest multiple next siblings selectors and call it a day" solution I mentioned in the OP. I think limiting the number of color controllers is a better way, for now. But thanks!

Comment: I see...  ok... removing answer shortly then :)

Comment: As I hadn't spelt it out, I think your answer is more than welcome to stay here.